# change part of a link with javascript in a specific div only

Tags: javascript, replace, innerhtml

Hi I need to edit some links on a page. Using the below code works but causes other problems on the page. I need the code to only affect elements with a certain input id. I also can't just replace the links as a query will be dynamically added to the end of each link. So in summary i just need to replace parts of all links with an input id "btnViewDetails". Any help would be great I'm very stuck. Cheers

```
<script language="javascript">

    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/JobSeekers/g,'mobile');
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/JobPositionDetail.aspx/g,'JobPositionDetail_Mobile.aspx');

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

`var someVariable = document.getElementsByClassName('btnViewDetails');`

(you should use class instead of ID, if it is not a unique value).

`someVariable` is now an array holding all elements with class name `btnViewDetails`.

Now replace the text you want to replace only on the href values of you elements (you will have to loop over them):

```
for (i = 0; i < someVariable.length; i++) {
  someVariable[i].href // do your replaces here
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply I've tried the below but it's not working. Do I still need to reference .innerHTML etc? Cheers `<script type="text/javascript">

var someVariable = document.getElementsByClassName('btnViewDetails');

for (i = 0; i < someVariable.length; i++) {
  someVariable[i].href.replace(/JobSeekers/g,'mobile');
  someVariable[i].href.replace(/JobPositionDetail.aspx/g,'JobPositionDetail_Mobile.aspx');

}

</script>`

Comment: I've also tried the below, it's very close but only changes text and not links any further suggestions would be great. thankyou


`<script type="text/javascript">
  
$('#btnViewDetails').each( function() { 
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/JobSeekers/g,'mobile'));
    });

</script>`